# How can I add a display order within a parent/child query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Simple table example:

```
CatID  |  ParentID  |  Name  |  DisplayOrder
============================================
1         NULL         A        1
2         1            A1       1
3         1            A2       2
4         NULL         B        2

etc.
```

I want to order by parents, and children within that parent. But I also want to obey the DisplayOrder. So first by parent by display order, and then children within each parent, by their display order. One level deep only. I want to avoid a complex query if possible, such as most CTE examples I've seen.

Well, this works

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT      

     CatID
    ,ParentID
    ,DisplayOrder AS LevelOne
    ,NULL AS LevelTwo

    FROM Table WHERE ParentID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
       c.CatID
      ,c.ParentID
      ,d.DisplayOrder AS LevelOne
      ,c.DisplayOrder AS LevelTwo

    FROM Table c WHERE ParentID IS NOT NULL
    INNER JOIN Table d ON c.ParentID = d.CatID
) AS Cats
ORDER BY Cats.LevelOne, Cats.LevelTwo
```

Okay so the above query works fine, but only on one condition... The DisplayOrder of the parents must be different. So if two parents have 1 as the DisplayOrder ( for whatever reason ), then result set ends up a complete mess. As long as I have the parent's display order in sequence, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc. Then it works. I understand *why*, but trying to find the best solution to solve it and account for the possibility of duplicate display orders.

Comment: try using `DisplayOrder+' - '+CatID` for the parents `LevelOne` may need a convert based on the data types...

Comment: @DanielE. Problematic that way. If I have a ID of 500, and a Display Order of 0, and another Cat with ID of 1 and a display order of 1... Well you can see how this will end up out of order depending on the CatID

Comment: `0 - 500` would come before `1 - 1`, what is the issue?

Comment: @DanielE. I read right past the concat ' - ' part. Giving this a try now.

Comment: @DanielE. This is beautifully simple and works fine. Unless there's a gotcha  somewhere down the road, seems to be perfect. Please post this as an answer, as I was looking for something simple to solve the direct issue, trying to avoid CTEs for just a one level deep situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will allow you to sort properly without jumping through hoops, feel free to change the data types, just remember if the variables in `DisplayOrder + ' - ' + CatID` are `int` it will evaluate as `1+0+1=2` not `'1 - 1'`

```
CREATE TABLE #table (
    CatID INT PRIMARY KEY
    ,ParentID INT NULL
    ,NAME VARCHAR(50)
    ,DisplayOrder INT
    );

INSERT #table
VALUES (1,NULL,'A',1)
    ,(2,1,'A1',1)
    ,(3,1,'A2',2)
    ,(4,NULL,'B',2);

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT CatID
        ,ParentID
        ,Convert(VARCHAR(50), DisplayOrder) 
            + ' - ' 
            + Convert(VARCHAR(50), CatID) AS LevelOne 
        ,NULL AS LevelTwo
    FROM #table
    WHERE ParentID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.CatID
        ,c.ParentID
        ,Convert(VARCHAR(50), d.DisplayOrder) 
            + ' - ' 
            + Convert(VARCHAR(50), d.CatID) AS LevelOne
        ,c.DisplayOrder AS LevelTwo
    FROM #table c
    INNER JOIN #table d ON c.ParentID = d.CatID
    WHERE c.ParentID IS NOT NULL
    ) AS Cats
ORDER BY Cats.LevelOne
    ,Cats.LevelTwo;

DROP TABLE #table
```

This results in:

```
CatID   ParentID    LevelOne    LevelTwo
1       NULL        1 - 1       NULL
2       1           1 - 1       1
3       1           1 - 1       2
4       NULL        2 - 4       NULL
```